# Browser side CSS abstract syntax tree generator. (JavaScript but not Node)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking for a client-side standalone JavaScript library (if it runs on Node then I can't use it) that consumes a string of text (that has valid CSS) and produces a CSS Abstract Syntax Tree. Something like JavaScript AST visualizer: http://jointjs.com/demos/javascript-ast but for CSS.

It has to be client-side standlone JavaScript, NOT Node.

Thanks in advance for all your answers!!

Comment: What should output be?

Comment: something like this : [
  {
    "selector": "p",
    "rules": [
      {
        "directive": "color",
        "value": "black"
      }
    ]
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could use [gonzales](https://github.com/css/gonzales/) css parser? its for node but [it can be used on browser with browserify](http://codetheory.in/parsing-css-in-javascript)

Comment: But how do i get the gonzales.js file without having  node or npm installed (which i don't have)?. If i could get that file then it'd probably be what i need.

Comment: there is [this simple example website](http://ast.csspatterns.com/) which could probably be reverse engineered, if it is what you need i may try it

Comment: actually here [gonzales-ast](https://github.com/stoyan/gonzales-ast) its the project page of the parser i said on the other comment the code for the demo is at the demo folder

Comment: Thanks that was wthat i was looking for! I can use that demo on my project.